# I need some help with the verbe « relationner » please. 

Tags: verbes

[CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Relationner) says the definition of « relationner » is

> 1. *« Établir une relation entre, avec deux ou plusieurs éléments, mettre des personnes en relation. »*
> 2. *« Entrer en relation (avec quelqu’un). »*

[image]

So the definition means

1. *“to establish a relation between two or several things, to put people in touch.”* and
2. *“to enter into a relationship (with someone).”*

**does definition 2 also mean “to get into contact with sb?”**

So I understand the definitions lol. However, I’m having trouble coming up with some example sentences. So please could you provide some very simple sentences.

---

Also, the following are examples that I’ve come up with. Please can you let me know If I’ve used the verb correctly.

(1) For the sentence “I’m establishing a relation between my bed and sleep.”, are

**« Je relationne mon lit avec sommeil. »** & **« Je relationne mon lit à dormir. »** correct?

(2) For the sentence “I know a music producer who can help you with your music. Do you want to get in touch (with him)?”, is

**« Je connais un producteur de musique qui peut vous aider avec votre musique. Voulez-vous relationner (avec lui) ? »** correct ?

(3) For the sentence “She told me she has a crush on you! Do you want to enter into a relationship with her?” is

**« Elle m’a dit que elle au béguin pour toi! Est-ce que tu veux relationner avec elle ? »** correct?

---

By the way, my french level is ***beginner*** thus please can you make any explanation as simple as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't waste too much time with such a little-used verb:

[image]

not to mention my spellchecker underlines it with a wavy red line...

The second quote in the TLFi looks to me like a joke more than anything.

Anyway, here is what I can comment about your attempts.

(1) « Je relationne mon lit avec sommeil. » & « Je relationne mon lit à dormir. »

Neither of these sentence do work. They aren't grammatical. You might say *je relationne avec mon lit en dormant*.

(2) « Je connais un producteur de musique qui peut vous aider avec votre musique. Voulez-vous relationner (avec lui) ? » correct ?

Yes but *avec lui* is mandatory.

(3) « Elle m’a dit **qu'elle a le béguin** pour toi! Est-ce que tu veux relationner avec elle ? »

Correct. It remind's me when people having no clue about what it means were singing *voulez-vous coucher avec moi, ce soir*...

Edit: This verb is possibly a quebecism, or at least more frequent in Canadian French.

Comment: Thanks @jlliagee for your help! I’m a bit confused. (1) Why is it ugly? (2) Is it a made-up verb? (3) What is TLFi ? Is that the same thing as CNTRL?

Comment: 1. I can't really explain. That's more of a native speaker feeling. 2. A neologism, but all words started as neologisms if we look far enough in the past... 3. The TLFi is *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, a still excellent online dictionary written a few decades ago. The CNTRL (Centre national de ressources textuelles et lexicales) is a research web site where you can find many linguistic resources, including the TLFi.

Comment: Thank you for the information @jlliagre ! Just so I can be finished with this verb, please could you look at my sentences above and tell me I used the verb correctly.

Comment: There is no way to use this verb correctly. Everyone will stare at you if you do it and at best think you are joking.

Comment: Oh. Hmm... I’m a bit confused lol . So then why is the verb stated in TLFi?

Comment: It is not really stated as an entry. It is just as a sub-entry to *relation*. It is so much rare that most native French would probably think this verb doesn't exist, but of course, everyone would understand what its intended meaning is. I'm going to try to sort out your attempts anyway.

Comment: Jamais entendu dans l'hexagone, *relationner* fleur bon "La Belle Province" mais vous étiquette ‘plouc’ dans les milieux germanopratins, le fil rouge du *ngram* est à suivre de ce côté de l'Atlantique :-) — Faire l'amour, c'est glamour, coucher c'est le pied … avec tout cela, les franchouillards ont des tendances grivoises avec les mots, avec relation privée en particulier.

Comment: @Personne Flûte ! je me serais fait surprendre par un québécisme...

Comment: @jilliagre you might want to remove "ugly" from your answer then to avoid looking offensive :-)

Comment: @LaurentS.  … ou plutôt accompagner *ugly* (qui est en France *laid, moche, vulgaire*) de *québécisme*

Comment: Jamais entendu. L'adjectif _relationné_, début 20e, av. 1922, Proust ; le verbe, 1957 Jankélévitch ; les deux rares. Au Québec on a _relationniste_, spécialiste des relations publiques. (DHLF)